# Two different /site-packages on macos

Tags: python, macos, pip

I want to use flask, I have installed it twice. I have two different site-packages directories for python.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

After installing pip I wanted to use it so I made an alias to the path

```
alias pip='/usr/local/bin/pip3.7'
```

having this I tried to install flask

```
pip install flask
```

This did install flask to:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask
```

But when I tried to use it within the python prompt

```
$ python 
>>>import flask
```

I got an error for 'flask', the code wouldn't run. So I figured I would try installing it with sudo

```
sudo pip install flask
```

This then introduced me this path:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

So this time when I tried to import flask, it worked!

```
$ python
>>> import flask
>>>
```

So, my question is which /site-packages directory should I alias `pip` to? I'm guessing should change to the `Library/Frameworks` one since that got my flask import working but I'm not sure.

Any information or recommendations on these two paths would be great, I'm new to the mac+python workflow.

Comment: Check the path of the Python executable that you run when you type `python`. Type `which -a python` and the one you run will be first. Install libraries to match the Python executable that you are using. (And why do you need two, anyway?)

Comment: Hi, `which -a python` returns `/usr/bin/python` but python would originally run version 2 for me so I added an alias python='python3'. So when I do `which -a python3` it outputs both `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3` and `/usr/local/bin/python3`. I get the same thing for pip. When I do `which -a pip3.7` I get both directories.

Comment: Well since you created an alias, that's what you get when you type `python`. Realize that each python comes with its own directories and its own `pip`. Put flask in the library that corresponds with the Python you want to use. Does that tell you something you didn't know? I'm not really sure what you are struggling with, to be honest.

Comment: This should help with all these kinds of _pip_ related issues: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- In short, never use any of the `pip` or `pipX.Y` scripts directly, but always prefer the safer way of calling _pip_'s executable module for a specific Python interpreter explicitly: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

to see what you have in your Python. I suspect your pip and python does not match, e.g., one from homebrew and another come with macOS (which might make your module incompatible if they are compiled binaries). The above command prints where your python console will look for a module. If that doesn't fit where your pip will install to, try set up PYTHONPATH before running python, e.g., in bash

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
python
```

Comment: I got the error when I try to open my .bashrc or .bash_profile: `Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 3.x but you are running Python 2.x!`. But then figured out that I had the path set already in my bash_profile! It must have been homebrew. I think they are matching up now. Thanks for the sys.path tip!